# Filtrando dados no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela  chamada **tb_codigos** contendo as seguintes colunas: **cod**,**txt1**,**txt2**

Preciso somar a quantidade de caracteres das duas colunas **txt1** e **txt2**, no exemplo abaixo o tamanho dos caracteres é 6, quando tento filtrar todos os registros que tenham mais de 1 caractere ele dá erro, teoricamente deveria aparecer todos os registros. Seria algum erro de sintaxe?

Exemplo:

```
cod     txt1    txt2  tamanho
1       abc     abc   6
2       abc     abc   6
3       abc     abc   6
4       abc     abc   6
```

Sql:

```
SELECT
cod,
txt1,
txt2
COALESCE (sum(
character_length(txt1)+
character_length(txt2)+
)) AS 'tamanho' 
FROM tb_codigos 
where tamanho > 1
GROUP BY cod
order by tamanho desc
```

Comment: Você não pode fazer um `WHERE` com um alias, utilize o `HAVING` colque após o `GROUP BY`.
Retire o `WHERE` e deixe assim `GROUP BY cod HAVING tamanho > 1 ORDER BY tamanho DESC`

Comment: Agora deu certo, não sabia que where com alias não funcionava

Comment: @arllondias sugiro você colocar isso como uma resposta, ou alguém fará isso e ganhará seus créditos :P

Comment: @rLinhares feito =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode usar alias em uma cláusula `WHERE`

Ou você pode usar a própria `query`, que ficaria dessa maneira:

```
SELECT
  cod,
  txt1,
  txt2
  COALESCE (sum(
              character_length(txt1)+
              character_length(txt2)
            )) AS tamanho 
FROM tb_codigos 
where COALESCE (sum(
              character_length(txt1)+
              character_length(txt2)
            )) > 1
GROUP BY cod
ORDER BY tamanho desc;
```

Ou usando a `HAVING` que eu aconselho a usar, pois não precisa repetir a contagem da string, ficaria dessa maneira:

```
SELECT
      cod,
      txt1,
      txt2
      COALESCE (sum(
                  character_length(txt1)+
                  character_length(txt2)
                )) AS tamanho 
    FROM tb_codigos 
    GROUP BY cod
    HAVING tamanho > 1
    ORDER BY tamanho desc;
```